# Error: 'b' argument of 'sign' intrinsic at (1) must be the same type and kind as 'a'

Tags: linux, fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran77

I am new in Fortran. So I need help.
I'm using gfortran on SUSE to compile my code and receive the following error:

```
DELTAL = SIGN (.1,(GFIX-GAMFLT))
```

1

```
Error: 'b' argument of 'sign' intrinsic at (1) must be the same type and kind as 'a'
```

Main file for code is attached in the below link where at 3509 line shows the error

https://files.engineering.com/getfile.aspx?folder=d55e28c0-10bf-4c50-b07f-c1de071c9567&file=sftol.f

How to fix this one?

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Minimal example ?

Comment: A minimal example includes a `program programname` statement, variable declarations, and code (strip out the thousands of lines if you can and just include the lines causing your error) and an `end program` statement. This way we can compile what you have if we have too.

Comment: As a guess, if GFIX and GAMFLT are double precision (real*8) then the .1 needs to be the same. You can do this with `0.1d0`.

Comment: Yes, Dan Sp. I did the edit like you said and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was finally solved as follows:

```
DELTAL = SIGN (0.1D0,(GFIX-GAMFLT))
```

This seems it preserves the basic datatype of the original code. It does compile successfully.

Thanks to all for your suggestions.